# Linear Hypothesis Tests

Tags: regression, linear

I have questions about linearHypothesis() function in the car package. I would like to see the post hoc comparisons of the interaction A:B, e.g. is A significant when B is "1"? I read the manuscript but really couldn't understand it. Can anyone help me, please?

Here is the model:

Here is only a small proportion of data here. All main effects (A and B) and interaction (A: B) are significant when analyzing all data.

```
data <- data.frame(response = c(2.113971041, 2.173632272, 2.219770569, 2.134824826, 2.166393449, 2.157404488, 2.210344692, 2.227377043, 2.156442964, 2.128198921, 2.148816937, 2.114781136, 2.109805286, 2.136088431, 2.173248823, 2.144420568, 2.150403812, 2.139765566, 2.155469055, 2.211422375, 2.234765463, 2.140362475, 2.209247242, 2.142706624, 2.231722603, 2.22248126, 2.061845745, 2.175145536, 2.19810209, 2.205595062, 2.102708676, 2.136712975, 2.115583827, 2.148280697, 2.14554293, 2.113153423, 2.23670075, 2.110654221, 2.132237708, 2.095014217, 2.131578052, 2.138558314, 2.216338269, 2.17589011, 2.107209036, 2.200700982, 2.167651698, 2.085528692, 2.063241116, 2.239346261, 2.143282059, 2.219955364, 2.234483079, 2.117948605, 2.116379227, 2.137332762, 2.155957575, 2.204407391, 2.228178965, 2.197301128 ),
                          A = c(-1.110415973, -1.508355982, 1.146315918, -2.164773636, 0.219280945, -1.909501131, -1.237061174, -0.843935247, -0.591128579, 0.305734857, -1.283960044, -2.136744912, 0.817135534, 0.028165327, -0.167970197, 1.953038809, 0.138422422, -0.57519634, 1.013281976, 1.109014444, -0.005406994, -0.8030458, 1.075492647, -0.485951873, 1.693510852, 0.869266273, 1.376605887, 0.475442705, -0.982930048, -1.548473205, 0.60460369, -1.161887948, -1.276406906, 0.51216372, 0.726466385, 0.233282169, -1.772663171, 0.211316444, -0.761081298, -1.200985808, 0.672730629, 0.651953625, -0.111439047, 0.640228528, 0.985737197, 0.425027082, 0.002937438, -0.750915294, -0.610082619, -0.944665548, 0.488245815, -0.008628479, 0.071259511, 1.306752766, 0.955229635, -1.010451122, -2.562713644, -0.401345642, 1.074392322, -1.372381946 ),
                   B = c(0.162721905, -0.627893023, 0.2485954, 0.226055126, 0.061257769, -1.897438622, -0.468594258, -0.194959882, 0.354859812, 0.377998921, -0.823092817, -2.570854522, 1.042152768, 0.374430051, 0.719774405, 0.83283342, 0.296276107, 0.681254006, 0.681558366, 0.310705696, -0.767442432, -0.745992335, 0.115428087, 0.469578271, 1.197345136, 1.047483276, 0.236048177, 0.724690829, -1.509534632, -0.775012686, 0.022808795, -0.478357524, 1.085801689, 0.484431375, 1.021224578, -0.932420125, -0.06591339, 0.431591624, -0.971187344, -1.306919465, 0.382097506, -0.501202686, -0.737924714, 0.843845241, 1.53906801, -0.291147475, -0.41458502, -1.933298819, -0.56333183, 0.065291562, -0.20098651, 0.540053236, -1.081035069, 0.853231573, 0.60928081, -0.568000441, -2.010067921, -0.471204232, 0.073778818, -0.803902656 ))


m1 <- lm(response ~ A*B, data = data)

library(car)
linearHypothesis(m1,c(0,1,0,1))
# linearHypothesis(m1,c(intercept, A, B, A:B))
```

plot:

```
library(effects)
effectXY<-as.data.frame(effect("A:B", m1))
ggplot(effectXY, aes(y=fit, x=A, colour=B ))+
  geom_smooth(aes( group=B ),method="lm",size=0.6)+
  geom_point(aes())+
  geom_errorbar(aes ( ymin=fit-se, ymax=fit+se,  width=0.3))
```

[image]

output:

```
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
A  + A:B = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: response ~ A * B

  Res.Df     RSS Df  Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1     57 0.12733                            
2     56 0.12691  1 0.00041974 0.1852 0.6686
```

Does it mean that A is not significant when B is 1?

Comment: Where did you get the coefficients for the test: `c(0,1,0,1)` ?

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico Hi Sal, I would like to know if A becomes significant when B = 1. So I set the main variable of A to 1 [c(0,1....)] and the interaction of A:B to 1[c(0,1,0,1)]. Am I doing this right?

Comment: I don't think that's right.  As far as I understand that function, your code tests against the null hypothesis that the coefficient for `A` plus the coefficient for `A:B` is zero.  The low *p*-value tells you that there is evidence against this null hypothesis.  For example, the following returns a *p*-value of essentially 1: `library(car); mod.davis=lm(weight~repwt,data=Davis); summary(mod.davis); linearHypothesis(mod.davis,c(1/5.3363, -1/0.9278))` .

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you are trying to do, and maybe include a reproducible toy data set ?   I'm guessing you want to look at post-hoc comparisons on the interaction term `A:B`, and specifically look how the levels of `A` compare to one another when `B` is "1"...

Comment: @Sal Mangiafico Thanks! Yes, you're right, I'd like to see a post-hoc comparison on the interaction. For example, is A significant when B = 1? I have changed my question and included some data this time.

Comment: With your addition of some example data, I am even more confused.  A and B are presumably both continuous variables.  You have no observation where B=1, so what would it mean to ask if A is significant when B=1 ?  Maybe if you could give some (hypothetical) context where this makes sense.  For example, if you had some scale for happiness used as a dependent variable, and you are using people's height and weight as independent variables, all continuous, how could it make sense to ask if *Weight* is significant when *Height* is 2 meter, unless you had a group of subjects that were all 2 m tall ?

Comment: Also, your plot and your data don't match.

Comment: @SalMangiafico Hi Sal, I have included the code for the plot. I used the effects package, which says: "The function Effect may similarly be used to produce an effect display for any combination of predictors". I was asked to do post hoc comparisons. But I don't know what to do when all independent variables are continuous. If this way is not feasible, what way do you recommend for post hoc comparisons when all independent variables are continuous? Thank you!!

Comment: It appears the `effect()` function reduces your 60 observations to 25 observations, and categorizes  `A` and `B` into 5 categories each.  Is this what you want ?

Comment: I believe so. Also, I am a little curious, if I code like this, linearHypothesis(m1,c(0,1,0,1)), does the result show that A is not significant when B is 1? Or suggest that B is not significant when A is 1?

Comment: No.  The output tells you the hypothesis that is being tested: `Hypothesis: A  + A:B = 0`, and this appears to refer to the actual coefficients in the output from `summary()` model.

Comment: If you want to categorize your independent variables, then you would have to come up with a reasonable method to do so.  There are different options to do so.  Personally, I wouldn't rely on the `effects()` function, since I don't know how it categorizes continuous independent variables.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions!